# Iterating through links causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have the following structure:

```
struct page {
    int index;
    int noutlinks;
    node* inlinks;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
};

struct node {
    page* page;
    node* next;
};

struct config {
    node* list;
};
```

From this structure, I used the following code to call all the values that are stored inside my sample test.

```
void DumpInfo(node* list){
    for (node* iter = list; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next) {

        if(iter->page->inlinks == 0){
            result = first + dampener * 0;

        }

        printf("PAGE: %s ", iter->page->name);
        printf("INDEX: %zd ", iter->page->index);
        printf("IN: %zd ", iter->page->inlinks);
        printf("OUT: %zd ", iter->page->noutlinks);


    }
```

When I print this out, I get the following values

```
PAGE: A INDEX: 0 IN: 6972112 (B, D) OUT: 0
PAGE: B INDEX: 1 IN: 6972048 (D)    OUT: 2
PAGE: C INDEX: 2 IN: 6972144 (B, D) OUT: 0
PAGE: D INDEX: 3 IN: 0              OUT: 3
```

For Page A it contains INPUT of Page B, D. What I'm trying to achieve is getting the OUT values from B and D.

I have tried the code below which seems to grab the incorrect output and then crash with a segmentation fault

```
int res = 0;

        for(node* in = list; in != NULL; in = in-> next){
            node* inlink = in->page->inlinks;
            res = inlink->next->page->noutlinks;
            printf("RESULT: %d\n", res);
        }
```

How do I grab the values of out for each input without causing a segmentation fault?

Comment: Common guideline: always do a NULL check before dereferencing a pointer variable.

Comment: How do you create your list?

Comment: Common guideline #2 - learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: What part of code prints `(B, D)`?

Comment: @MohitJain I was just writing the actual input beside it, (the print statement only prints the numbers)

Comment: Are you using a C compiler, or a C++ compiler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,

1. `node* inlink = in->page->inlinks;`

   will segfault if `in->page` is NULL.
2. `inlink->next->page->noutlinks;`

   will segfault if `inlink`, `inlink->next` or `inlink->next->page` is NULL.

because, NULL pointer dereference (*at runtime, to be specific*)  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: Add NULL check for a pointer before dereferencing.

---

*I think you're missing to show us a couple of `typedef`s, without which, your code will not compile.*

Comment: NULL check as in something like in->page != NULL right? I tried that using  if(inlink->next->page != NULL || inlink != NULL || inlink->next != NULL){ but it seems to do the same :/

Comment: @KadanaKanz you need to change the order of check ,IMHO, do something like `if( (inlink != NULL) && (inlink->next != NULL) && (inlink->next->page != NULL))` otherwise, in the process of checking only, you'll be dereferencing the NULL pointer, and use `&&`, not `||`.

Answer (score -1):

In your code,

```
struct page {
    int index;
    int noutlinks;
    node* inlinks;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
};

struct node {
    page* page;
    node* next;
};

struct config {
    node* list;
};
```

*(Assuming that you don't have `typedef`s written)* should `page* page;` be `struct page* page`, and
should `node* next;` be `struct node* next` ?

By the way, your code does not compile without the changes I pointed out to. If I assume that you have `typedef`d them and have not added that part here, then during runtime your code will end up receiving `SIGSEGV` i.e. Segmentation Fault if `inlink->next->page` is NULL or `inlink->next` is NULL.